Uploading images to Firebase storage returns "Access denied" after some time
I have been using the following code to upload images on Firebase Storage:
const file = admin
    .storage()
    .bucket()
    .file("my path to save the image")
const mainPromise = file
    .save(buffer, { resumable: false, contentType: "auto" })
    .then(() => file.getSignedUrl({ action: "read", expires: "03-17-2100" }))
    .then(([url]) => url)

const url = await Promise.resolve(mainPromise) 

Recently, I migrate the function containing the above snipped code to the 2nd gen (2nd gen upgrade).
The updated function runs with a different service account with the following roles:

roles/datastore.importExportAdmin
roles/deploymentmanager.editor
roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator

With the current setup, I am able to:

upload images using the GCP callable function from the frontend;
get access to the images with the signed url created during upload.

However, with some images uploaded after the 2nd gen migration, I received the following error when I'm trying to open an image (after some time from the upload time):
<Error>
    <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
    <Message>Access denied.</Message>
    <Details>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method.</Details>
    <StringToSign>GET 4108924800 "the image path I'm trying to get..."</StringToSign>
</Error>

Do I need to specify a specific role for the service account in a 2nd gen function to upload file to the storage and been able to retrieve them after some time (i.e. months)?
Or is there something else that I'm missing here?

seems the issue is related to the use of v4 URLs as explained here. gstuil generates v4 URLs by default. These URLs have a max expiry of 7 days. Also check this link & GitHub

Thanks @SathiAiswarya for your answer.
Does it mean that if I don't specify the version in the signedurl config, I get the v4 as default?
The other links that you attached refer to the content type value, and that is something that was unchanged for a long time...

As per the GitHub gsutil generates v4 URLs by default. Also, check this link and GitHub

I understand what you are saying but right now I can access URLs generated on the 1st of December... Which means that I'm not using the v4 for generating URLs then...

Try this workaround suggested here  create a different service account and see

What you are suggesting is a workaround for future situations. What I am looking for is a solution for the current behaviour...

After a discussion with the Firebase Support, we have found the reason why the signed url returns a SignatureDoesNotMatch error.
When we initialized the admin, we did NOT specify the credentials:
const admin = require("firebase-admin")
const dotenv = require("dotenv")
dotenv.config()

admin.initializeApp({
    storageBucket: process.env.ADMINCONFIG_STORAGEBUCKET,
})
module.exports = admin

Thus, Google Cloud will create a SYSTEM_MANAGED key with 16 days expiration date and use the key for signing the URLs.
Hence, after the key used for signing the URL is automatically revoked by Google Cloud, the url is no longer valid and will returns the SignatureDoesNotMatch error.
If we don’t specify a private key for the service account, the Firebase Admin SDK will using the default credentials (in your case "SYSTEM_MANAGED" type key). This usually works in environments like Google Cloud, Firebase Hosting, or local emulators authenticated via gcloud CLI.
